# https is downgraded when navigating through the Stack Exchange web

Tags: bug, ssl

Visiting https://stackoverflow.com/ and then navigating to other sites of the Stack Exchange network through the top menu bar, then the other sites are called without https.

The links in the menu should be fixed.